# BMW E90 2005, 318D to 320 engine question

Tags: engine, bmw, computer

I am owner of BMW 320d e90 2005 sedan. My car's engine had to be replaced, so I found another car which has the same engine but is technically 318d.

Can you tell me if I can swap the engines without changing anything?
Basically what I want to do it place the 318d engine (which should be exactly the same 2l 1995cm3 diesel engine) in the 320d place.

As I've done some research on other forums - people stated that it is basically just a detuned engine, so if we connect the 318d to 320d computer it should be same thing, or there might be other things to change?

Comment: The engine harness may be different if the sensors have different connectors or has different sensors in different locations, unless someone has done this exact swap and documented it, it is a project. Yes the ecu need the one that is for that engine as the software is different even if it is the same part number. Post back here with an answer if you get it done successfully!

Answer (score 1):

The 319d engine is simply a 320d but detuned. As far as I know there is a difference in the fuel injectors and the ECU mapping.

319d fuel injector are Bosch #0445110209 while 320d/323d are #0437502006.

ECU might work, but will probably have to be reprogrammed or replaced with a 318d ECU.

Answer (score -1):

You should change the engine **with** the matching components such as the ecu.

This is because the engine control parameters are different between the engines. In fact, if you don’t fit the matching ecu it may not even start.

I put an engine from one manufacturer into a car from a different manufacturer - the detail you have to check is down to you - miss something and you find out later...

At least the engine / gearbox connection should be easy unless car A was manual and car B auto...

Comment: is it just the ecu? also if you check the specs the engines are the same 4 cylincer 1995cm3 2l

Comment: I put “matching components such as”...

Comment: What other components I might need to change except the ECU?

Comment: If you plan on swapping the ecu with the engine then you will need to do a lot of work to make sure it integrates with the rest of your car properly, mainly the immobilizer system.  If your original ecu is same part number with only different software then you can just flash the proper software needed to your original ecu via bdm or tools like inpa or winkfp.